# Signaling on related model when deleting ForeignKey in django

Tags: python, django, django-signals

In django, is there any way to be signalised about a change in the related model when the foreignKey is set with `on_delete=models.SET_NULL`?

In a first scenario with the typical situation:

```
class RelatedModel(models.Model):
    fKey = models.ForeignKey('ForeignModel')

class ForeignModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

fk = ForeignModel.objects.create(name='Test')
rm = RelatedModel()
rm.fKey = fk
rm.save()
fk.delete()
```

When fk.delete() is called, the `pre_delete` and `post_delete` signals will be triggered for both `fk` and `rm` objects.

If, however, the RelatedModel is declared as:

```
class RelatedModel(models.Model):
    fKey = models.ForeignKey('ForeignModel', null=True, on_delete=SET.NULL)
```

I don't see the any signal being trigged for the related model, even though it has changed (the `fKey` value was changed to null). The only signal that is trigged are the pre/post delete signals for `fk`.

Given this situation, is there any way to be signalised about the change in the related model and still using `on_delete=models.SET_NULL` and not writing a custom method?

Answer (score 0):

SET_NULL is just a callable, taking some arguments. So, you may define your own SIGNALING_SET_NULL and send a signal of your choice.